# Git repo size increment on commit

Tags: git, version-control

I've read articles on how to get the size of a commit, how to get size of repo and stuff, but this one I couldn't find. Imagine you have a repo with some `.txt` stuff in it. A new commit comes with a change in for example one line. A git preserve versions of each file afaik.

I'd like to know how does the size of whole repo increase with that one commit. Does it increase only by the `change` you commit or is there some bond between the newest version and the previous one(diff) so git increments the size of repo by `diff + changes` or is there some weird behavior where git would preserve `the whole file + diff + changes` on each commit? Or something else?

And also, is there some `constant size` you'd get(git info about file/commit?) when you'd add 1byte to a repo with a single file, commit and substract that final repo size by the 1byte? I mean, how big is that "shell" of your commit changes?

Comment: git compresses in bulk when the payoff for packing things up looks gratifying.  while random stuff is accumulating it does lighter compression.  exactly how much extra space on disk your stuff will take after either of those depends on ... pretty much everything.  git's repository size is afaik still the winnah and undisputed champeen for tinyness, and size does matter :-)